# XPATH not finding the text that is contained on the web - using contains(text())

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

On this website https://classicdb.ch/?quest=788

I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//div[contains(text(), 'Start')]").text
```

It finds the element and it returns

```
'Start: Kaltunk'
```

However when I try to find the element that contains "End" it doesn't finds anything.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//div[contains(text(), 'End')]").text
```

Why is this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below xpath.

```
//table//div[contains(.,'End:')]
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Explanation:** Edit 1

First of all let's see how many `text()` nodes are present under the target `div`.

[image]

So the div have 3 text nodes.

Let me elaborate the original xpath used by OP.

```
//div[contains(text(), 'End')]
 ^div present anywhere in the document
     ^which contains
               ^the **first** text() node with string value as `End`
```

When <kbd>contains()</kbd> is given as its first argument (in **div[argument]**), it takes the *string* value of the **first** node, but `End` appears in the second text node, not the first. That's the reason why the xpath did not worked.

We have 2 options to handle this.

**1) using text() as the first argument** - By that way it will get all text nodes under current context and then use `contains()` as a condition to check for the `text()` value that will match any text() node whose value contains `End` as shown below.

```
//div[text()[contains(., 'End')]]
^div present any where in the document
     ^which have text() node
             ^ that contains 'End`
```

Check the below screenshot:

[image]

By this time, you would got a question then why the first xpath (`//div[contains(text(), 'Start')]`) used by OP worked?

If you look at the text() nodes associated in the div, `Start` text is present in the 1st text() node itself, that's the reason why he was able to use that xpath.

[image]

**2) Using . to check in current node context** In simple terms when you say `.` it will check in the entire current element context for the `End`.

```
//div[contains(.,'End')]
```

If you don't limit the scopt to `//table` (at the beginning of the xpath) you will get 5 divs as the ancestor divs of the original div which have this text also be matched with the xpath. So  limit the scope to check with in the table like 
`//table//div[contains(.,'End')]

Comment: Yeah this works, can you explain why is the ., in there?
And why my code didn't work where for the "Start" it worked?

Comment: @supputuri Please explain what the problem and solution were?

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know if you have any questions. Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this/any answer is/was helpful to you and [Upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) for the benefit of the future readers.

Comment: @supputuri Just wow - thank you so much for taking the time to give such elaborate answer! Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. If you fell it's worthy of throwing some rewards :-) check [Can I award a bounty to an old answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) section how to do it.

Comment: I would just add one thing, which is that much of the explanation in this answer is specific to XPath 1.0. The expression `contains(text(), 'End')` in XPath 1.0 examines only the first text node; in XPath 2.0+ it throws an error if there is more than one text node (which is designed to stop people making this common mistake). In both cases using "." in place of "text()" is the right answer.

Comment: Currently Selenium supports XPath 1.0 only, so I did not covered this difference.